# Ici, le mot « supports » est-il un terme de la physique ?

Tags: sens, philosophie

[image]

Ici, le mot « supports » est-il un terme de physique? Que signifie-t-il ?

Comment: Le mot « support » n'est pas à ma connaissance spécifique à la physique, c'est un élément (matériel ou non) sur lequel s'appuie quelque chose. Je comprends ainsi : quand il atteint le tout petit (ce qui est observable au microscope) le physicien observe (découvre) les relations (rapports) entre les « objets observés » et non pas ce qui s'appuie sur eux.  Si je comprends bien avec la phrase suivante : le physicien qui observe les électrons voit le lien des électrons entre eux et non l'énergie dont ils sont le support. Un physicien dira peut-être que je dis des bêtises... possible !

Comment: @None — On ne peut savoir où est l'électron sans le détruire, on sait seulement qu'il est probablement en train de circuler sur ou à proximité d'une enveloppe sphérique *par rapport* au centre de cette dernière, il n'est pas *supporté* par une surface sphérique, mais gravite autour d'un point central… « Nous ne pouvons pas déterminer exactement la position de l’électron, car il a un comportement ondulatoire, mais nous pouvons déterminer un volume où l’électron est susceptible de se trouver, et c’est grâce aux nombres quantiques. » (les conclusions de l'auteur sont les siennes… pas lumineuses)

Comment: @None … en plusl'auteurl confond micrométrie et nanométrie pour en tirer des conclusions philosophiques… les physiciens ‘nobélisés’ ou pas ne font pas de telles erreurs et sont clairs dans leurs explications, même si leurs équations sont ardues.

Comment: @林剑锋 « … est-il un terme *de* physique/mathématique/philosophie/théâtre/boxe… » pas d'article lorsque l'on utilise un terme générique.

Comment: L'auteur est toujours Aron?  En toute science. on trouve des supports (materialité) et des rapports, qui sont un apport humain, des abstractions. Il aurait pu dire: les objets et les rapports entre eux. Ce sont les humains qui trouvent les rapports.

Comment: @Lambie … sauf que l'électron est une onde corpusculaire, les deux à la fois : une onde (pouvant avoir un  *rapport* avec le temps ou  la distance dont la force du mouvement peut être mesurée quand elle est stoppée (par un objet). Suivie du mot *quantique* la physique change de paradigme.

Comment: @Personne Un électron est **une particule** élémentaire, Donc, un objet, avec une materialité. Ce n'est pas un rapport. Ce que j'ai dit est mon interprétation. Le(s) rapports entre cette particulé et les autres ne sont pas un objet, une chose.

Comment: @Lambie … *mea culpa*, j'ai confondu électron et photon.

Comment: @Personne Mais si, tu avais raison. Un électron, comme un photon, peut être envisagé à la fois [comme une particule et comme une onde](https://www.astronomes.com/big-bang/dualite-onde-particule/). Tout dépend du phénomène considéré. Il y a bien sûr des différences si on s'intéresse à leurs vitesses et masses/absence de masse respectives, mais ils sont quantiques tous les deux, comme toi et moi d'ailleurs ;-)

Comment: @Lambie Oui, l'auteur est Aron.

Comment: @林剑锋 — Merci, vos questions permettent aux neurones francophones de s'interroger, d'échanger, parfois de se chamailler et de se rendre compte qu'il n'y a pas que la grammaire qui pose problème dans la maîtrise du français ! :-) :-) — PS, je porte aussi un prénom épicène (merci DeepL).

Comment: @jlliagre … toute vie n'étant possible qu'avec de l'eau et de la lumière (des astres, dont le soleil, mais pas que) elle est donc cosmique, ce qui interroge lorsque l'on découvre l'intrication des photons !

Comment: @Personne La vie telle qu'on la connaît, c'est sûr, mais est-ce que **toute** vie s'appuie forcément sur des molécules d'eau ? Rien ne permet de l'affirmer. Il y a peut-être des formes de vie exotiques qui s'appuient sur une autre chimie et d'autres environnements, voire même sur la matière noire ou d'autres choses étranges et inconnues...